# "must be superuser or have the same role to terminate other server processes" with PostgreSQL

Tags: permissions, postgresql-9.4, amazon-rds, aws, connections

Postgres 9.4.12 locally and 9.4.7 on AWS RDS.

There are two database users: `app` and `untrusted_dev` (the latter to mirror AWS RDS: `NOSUPERUSER INHERIT CREATEDB CREATEROLE NOREPLICATION`).  `app` is granted `app_user` (a group role) permissions.

1) `app_user` has CRUD permissions on all the normal app tables and functions, but cannot drop tables and so on.

2) `untrusted_dev` is used for schema migrations.

3) Before/after migration hooks revoke and then re-grant `CONNECT` privileges for `app_user` (hence the group role).  The before hook also kicks everyone out:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE datname='the_app_db' AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

As I understand it, this separation is good from a security point of view, so that if a user somehow gains control of the `app` user, their permissions are limited.

And running a migration on AWS RDS (with `app` users connected) does successfully boot them out.  Yet, running it on a local Postgres 9.4.12 instance (with `app` users connected) gives the error in the title in response to the `pg_terminate_backend()` call.

Why?  (I would expect the same behaviour locally and with RDS.  After all, RDS's `untrusted_dev`'s only difference is that it has `rds_superuser`, but that's [not actually a superuser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713375/permissions-for-pg-terminate-backend-on-amazon-rds).)

Also, if it's right that I get this error, how should a migration work if you need to boot users, but have no superuser permissions and have a separate login explicitly for the regular users whom you are trying to boot?

Comment: I've also tried making both the public schema and the postgres database owned by untrusted_dev like they are in RDS.  Same error still.

Comment: Does the "have the same role" part from the question/answer you linked to, apply in your situation?

Comment: @mustaccio It can't, if I want to maintain a separate between regular users (`app`) and the more privileged logins used for migration (`untrusted_dev`) per best practices.  That's kind of the crux of my question: How are you supposed to follow best practices here without getting an error?

Comment: @mustaccio Another very strange point, in that question, it's AWS RDS that gives the error.  For me, I get the error locally, and AWS RDS works fine!  Hmm...